# How to compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

So how do you compute $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$?

This is part of a larger question:

[image]

By using the definition of derivative $f'\left(x\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)}{x-x_0}$and  the L'hopital rule, I am able to simplfy this down to :

$2\:\times \:\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\:+\:3\times \lim _{x\to 0}\left(x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$

I know how to solve the cos part using the squeeze theorem. But How do solve the sin part? I cannot apply squeeze

Comment: It does not exist .

Comment: "This is part of a larger question:"  What larger question? That's not a question, that's a function. Also, avoid the use of images, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}x^2\cos\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)=0.$$And, if $x\ne0$,$$f'(x)=3x^2\cos\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right).$$Actually, the limit $\lim_{x\to0}2\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$ doesn't exist, since the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Yep, I am such an idiot I am so sorry,

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need L'Hospital rule?

Clearly $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2\cos (\frac{1}{x^2})$$

Isn't it?